# The binary representation of unsigned integer in Go

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

Is there a built-in function to convert a `uint` to a slice of binary integers `{0,1}` ?

```
>> convert_to_binary(2)
[1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such a function, however you can use `strconv.FormatUint` for that purpose.

Example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/J7KfLPbVq3)):

```
func Bits(i uint64) []byte {
    bits := []byte{}

    for _, b := range strconv.FormatUint(i, 2) {
         bits = append(bits, byte(b - rune('0')))
    }

    return bits
}
```

`FormatUint` will return the string representation of the given `uint` to  a base, in this case 2, so we're encoding it in binary. So the returned string for `i=2` looks like this: `"10"`. In bytes this is `[49 48]` as 1 is 49 and 0 is 48 in ASCII and Unicode. So we just need to iterate over the string, subtracting 48 from each rune (unicode character) and converting it to a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "fmt"
   "math/bits"
)

func unsigned(x uint) []byte {
   b := make([]byte, bits.UintSize)
   for i := range b {
      if bits.LeadingZeros(x) == 0 {
         b[i] = 1
      }
      x = bits.RotateLeft(x, 1)
   }
   return b
}

func trimUnsigned(x uint) []byte {
   return bytes.TrimLeft(unsigned(x), string(0))
}

func main() {
   b := trimUnsigned(2)
   fmt.Println(b) // [1 0]
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits#LeadingZeros